# Dell C1660w Driver

Tags: drivers, printing, dell

just installed Ubuntu on my old Dell laptop and its great.

However I am struggling getting drivers for my Dell C1660w printer. I have downloaded them form other sources but cant seem to get them onto my system.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Would be good to add a link to the sources you are referring to. Is it a deb package? Is it the source code so you have to compile it?

Answer (score -1):

If you know the name of the package file you are trying to install you can use the low-level package installer for Debian systems`dpkg` to install the driver onto your system.

The following command should do the trick:
`dpkg --install package_file`

Note of caution: The `dpkg` command is to be used if the package file you are installing has been downloaded from a source other than a repository (official source for updates). No dependency resolution is performed if you use the low-level `dpkg` program to perform the installation. If `dpkg` discovers a missing dependency, `dpkg` will exit with an error.